# Slanted columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

While doing some frontend stuff ago I stumbled across slanted/skewed/etc edges that were used especially on one-page layouts. In this case the principle behind this is quite simple to implement.

Today I found this sketch, that uses angled edges to separate columns, not rows:

[image]

And I was wondering, how this could be achieved. I simply can't figure out, how can I create a wrapper for the content, that aligns with the edges, especially if the content is long enough to scroll it. If I scroll, what happens to the images inside (imagine like 6 images on the bottom of the sketch, if they reach the top, only 4 would visible).

I guess the middle-col image will have a higher z-index, but there's still the question, how the text will be loaded initially regarding to the angled space, or there are only two rows and the image would be the background of the body. But will the second option also align the text correctly, if the div is transformed?

If anyone ever has worked with this or has experience, I'm interested to hear how this can be achieved.

Comment: Add the `background-image` to the `body` (or the container) , and for the nav and content, do not apply background color to them instead create another div (or `pseudo-element`) apply the background color to it and skew it (or rotate).

Comment: @Akshay Thanks for the reply, about a few seconds ago I just added this idea, but will this affect the div/text, especially when scrolling. Sqint the text or hide it?

Comment: Don't think it will affect the text

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying:

- **[CSS 2D Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew)**
- **[CSS Clipping Masks](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)**
- **[CSS Pseudo elements + Transforms](http://lawrencenaman.com/css/responsive-slanted-divs-with-css/)**
- The skewn background by itself (***if all else fails***)

Here is a **[nice article](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms)** formulating some of the stuff described above.

And here is **[another site](http://generatedcontent.org/post/26407228072/split-feature)**, which hosts the desired effect inside it.